# How do I extract elements from a list in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following lists:

```
dates = ['12/29/2020', '12/25/2020', '12/22/2020']
numbers = [ [1, 31, 35], [17, 23, 36], [29, 53, 56] ]
```

I used them to make a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date':dates,
        'nums': numbers
    }
)
```

This gives me a DataFrame with two columns. I want to break out the elements in the list to create 3 columns (one for each number in the list) to end up with the following DataFrame:

```
     date            num1 num2 num3 
0    '12/29/2020'    1    31   35
1    '12/25/2020'    17   23   36
2    '12/22/2020'    29   53   56
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new data frame from `nums` column by converting it to list first, and then concat with `date` column:

```
pd.concat([df.date, pd.DataFrame(df.nums.to_list()).add_prefix('num')], axis=1)

         date  num0  num1  num2
0  12/29/2020     1    31    35
1  12/25/2020    17    23    36
2  12/22/2020    29    53    56
```

Comment: Not that it's super important, but the numeric suffixes on the `num` columns should start at 1, according to OP's example.

Comment: @ddejohn Yep you're right. Just wonder if I should further complicate the code with this difference.

Comment: Likely not worth the effort :D

Comment: Not necessary. Index at 0 is fine as well. All answers were great (and similar) so I went with who was first.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new dataframe and join it back:

```
>>> df[['date']].join(pd.DataFrame(df['num'].tolist()).rename(lambda x: f'num{x + 1}', axis=1))
         date  num1  num2  num3
0  12/29/2020     1    31    35
1  12/25/2020    17    23    36
2  12/22/2020    29    53    56
>>>
```

Or just `add_prefix`:

```
>>> df[['date']].join(pd.DataFrame(df['num'].tolist()).add_prefix('num'))
         date  num0  num1  num2
0  12/29/2020     1    31    35
1  12/25/2020    17    23    36
2  12/22/2020    29    53    56
>>>
```

Comment: Not that it's super important, but the numeric suffixes on the `num` columns should start at 1, according to OP's example. Your second solution doesn't reflect this.

Comment: @ddejohn Well the OP could still use the first solution.

Comment: Sure, again, not that important, but a minor detail to note.

Comment: @ddejohn Psidom's answer is accepted...

Answer (score 2):

So the other answers sufficiently cover the case where you need to fix *an already existing dataframe*, but just in case you have the opportunity, it's much easier to simply fix your data *before* creating a dataframe:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: dates = ['12/29/2020', '12/25/2020', '12/22/2020']

In [3]: numbers = [[1, 31, 35], [17, 23, 36], [29, 53, 56]]

In [4]: nums = {f"num{i}": n for i, n in enumerate(zip(*numbers), 1)}

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": dates, **nums})

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
        dates  num1  num2  num3
0  12/29/2020     1    31    35
1  12/25/2020    17    23    36
2  12/22/2020    29    53    56
```

Or, another way:

```py
In [7]: data = [[date, *nums] for date, nums in zip(dates, numbers)]

In [8]: pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["dates", "num1", "num2", "num3"])
Out[8]:
        dates  num1  num2  num3
0  12/29/2020     1    31    35
1  12/25/2020    17    23    36
2  12/22/2020    29    53    56
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dataframe constructor like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(numbers, 
             index=dates, 
             columns=[f'num{i+1}' for i in range(len(numbers))])\
  .rename_axis('dates').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        dates  num1  num2  num3
0  12/29/2020     1    31    35
1  12/25/2020    17    23    36
2  12/22/2020    29    53    56
```